# How to Limit the Search Scope in VI/VIM?

Tags: vim, scope, find, text-editor, vi

Find and replace scope can be limited like this:

```
:16,256s/search_term/replacement/gc
```

I don't want to replace my search term with any other text, I just want to find them. I tried the following, but it didn't help:

```
:16,256/search_term # Notice that there is no 's' here
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the vim documentation:

> You can limit the search command "/" to a certain range of lines by including
>   \%>l items.  For example, to match the word "limit" below line 199 and above
>   line 300: >

```
/\%>199l\%<300llimit
```

This means: Match below line 199 and before line 300 and find the word `limit`.

Comment: okay so I tested it for you /search_pattern\%>16l\%<256l   
will find the word search_pattern between 16 & 256. The % sign means search all text and the >lessthan <greaterthan limit the search with the flag 'l'

Comment: You can also use `:.,300/foo//gc` and then hit 'q' to stop the match and then 'n' for the next match. Don't know if that's more convenient, though.

Comment: @jhwist +1, that's certainly easier for me to remember!

Comment: @jhwist Easier to remember, but it doesn't work :) This is the error I'm getting: "E486: Pattern not found: gc"

Comment: @vito. Oops, sorry, there is an 's' missing. It's supposed to read `:.,300s/foo//gc`

Comment: @jhwist: what does 's' in `:.,300s` stand for?

Answer (score 0):

Adapting  @jhwist solution, I find it easier to use markers
remember to say 'n' to changes and not to go off the end

```
 :'a,'bs/extrascost//gc
```