# Limiting search scope for code in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

How can I limit the search scope in Vim to the function/class/code block that the cursor is currently in, without having to figure out what the line numbers are? Being able to search in the visual selection would also do, as there are methods for selecting the current code block.

(Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192332/how-to-limit-the-search-scope-in-vi-vim) question, but more generic)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm going to just copy and paste the entire content of ["Searching with / and ?" (within a visual selection) from the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection#Searching_with_.2F_and_.3F).

> In visual mode, <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>?</kbd> will update
>   the visual selection just like any
>   other cursor-movement command (that
>   is, when in visual mode, searching
>   will extend the selection).
>
> In order to actually search within the
>   visual selection, you will need to use
>   the `\%V` atom, or use the markers
>   defined by the visual selection with
>   the `\%>'<` and `\%<'>` atoms. This is
>   best done by leaving the visual
>   selection with <kbd>Esc</kbd> before entering
>   your search. You may want to consider
>   a mapping to automatically leave
>   visual selection and enter the
>   appropriate atoms. For example:
>
> ```
> :vnoremap <M-/> <Esc>/\%V
> ```
>
> Using this mapping, you can press
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> in order to automatically fill
>   in a "range" for your search just like
>   using an Ex command with `:`. To use
>   this, move to the first line of
>   interest and press <kbd>V</kbd> to start
>   line-wise visual selection. Move down
>   (press <kbd>j</kbd> for a line or <kbd>}</kbd> for a
>   paragraph, etc). When you have
>   selected the area you want to search,
>   press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd>. The visual selection will
>   be removed, and a search command will
>   start. You will see:
>
> ```
> /\%V
> ```
>
> Add what you want to find, then press
>   <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For example, you may enter
>   green and see:
>
> ```
> /\%Vgreen
> ```
>
> When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, each occurrence
>   of "green" will be highlighted, but
>   only in the area that you had
>   previously selected.
>
> Here are two further examples that do
>   not use a visual selection. The first
>   command searches only in lines 10 to
>   20 inclusive. The second searches only
>   between marks a and b.
>
> ```
> /\%>9l\%<21lgreen
> /\%>'a\%<'bgreen
> ```

Comment: I should've found that. *facepalm*

Answer (score 3):

For brevity:

```
" tldr;
v i { <ESC> /\%Vsearch-term

" Search for search-term within the current code block (defined by curly braces {}).
" Begin in normal mode, then enter the following:

" enter visual mode
v

" look for stuff in-between the current...
i

" curly braces enclosure
{

" (now the enclosure should be highlighted)

" exit visual mode
<ESC>

" search the last visual mode selection for search-term
/\%Vsearch-term

" note: to search within other enclosures, you can substitute curly braces for: 
" - parenthesis, 
" - square brackets, 
" - or other enclosure pair characters
```