# How do you know what VIM help keyword to search?

Tags: vim

I was trying to google how to search within a scope in VIM and found this link. [Limiting search scope for code in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921752/limiting-search-scope-for-code-in-vim)

I wouldn't imagine to come up with the keyword "/\%V" to search help in VIM help. So, I'm wondering how most people get help from VIM help, like in this case.

Comment: `:help help`
In first attempt I try `:help ` following with any letter that I believe what I need find and then press `<Tab>` for autocomplete.

I can not explain it, it's a part of art of Vim maybe?

Comment: I’d never search for `/\%V` to start with. If I could remember that magic spell, I wouldn’t need to search for it! In such situations, I ask for `:help` on general topics such as `regex`, with the help of completion suggestions, then I skim the help page looking at the headings, or `/search` relevant keywords in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the right thing. Google is probably going to be your best bet. You can also use the vim help site, it has a search function built in: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/

Answer (score 1):

### General:

1. `:help help-summary` is a great document explaining how to search
   effectively.

### Using wildcard expansion

I've had the same frustration, but I just realised that you can use wildcard
expansion when searching.

In your case it wouldn't have helped, but possibly if you'd started with `:h pattern` and then searched in that page for key words related to what you were
trying to achieve you might have found it.

In my case I was looking for a page I'd been on before only the other night,
`:h ex-cmd-index`, (on a different machine, so I couldn't search my command
history) but I could only remember than it had to do with ex commands, and had
the word index in there. I spent 20 mins trying to find it unsuccessfully (I
eventually googled it just so I could then return to vim and look it up...). I
was trying `ex` + `Tab` and being shown hundreds of possibilities...

But with wildcard expansion, I can just do `:h ex*index*` and hit `Tab` and I
get a shortlist of two possibilities, ('ex-cmd-index' and 'ex-edit-index')  one
of which was the one I wanted!

So as long as you have an idea of the order that things should appear in the
help topic, you should be able to narrow down the possibilities much faster.

### Using :helpgrep

There is a in-built command `:helpgrep` which puts every line matching a
pattern into a quickfix list. Then you can jump through each line with the
`:cnext` and `cprev` commands.

### Fuzzy search the help with fzf (and optionally ag-silver-searcher)

The [fzf plugin](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) has the command `:Helptags` to do a fuzzy search on... the
help tags. This is very nice.

In case all the above fails, I added a few functions to search the *entire*
contents (not just help-tags) of all the files in the vim's help doc directory
using [ag-silver-searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) and [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim).

First is a function that I found on an issue on the fzf github repo. I have no
idea how it works, but the command that calls this function allows me to search
the contents of a directory using ag, which pumps the results into fzf:

```
" Ag: Start ag in the specified directory e.g. :Ag ~/foo

function! s:ag_in(bang, ...)
  if !isdirectory(a:1)
    throw 'not a valid directory: ' .. a:1
  endif
  " Press `?' to enable preview window.
  call fzf#vim#ag(join(a:000[1:], ' '),
              \ fzf#vim#with_preview({'dir': a:1}, 'right:50%', '?'), a:bang)
endfunction

" Ag call a modified version of Ag where first arg is directory to search
command! -bang -nargs=+ -complete=dir Ag call s:ag_in(<bang>0, <f-args>)
```

So I wrote a function (`Help_Ag`) that calls the above command, and supplies
the directory containing the vim help docs (141 .txt files, plus a handful of
other files (a README, the tag files themselves etc).

If we select a help page to open, we set it to non-nomodifiable. I noticed that
not all the tags worked, and some redirected to the wrong page (e.g. a tag like
`*help-topic*` would take me to a page called `help` if the cursor was on that
word, and take me to `topic` if the cursor was on that word, whereas the in
real help, I would be taken to `help-topic`). I found that if I opened the real
help, the tags would start behaving normally in files selected with ag+fzf. So
I simply open and close the real help to trigger this behaviour (it's too quick
to even see, so I'm happy enough with this hack):

```
function! Help_Ag()
    let orig_file = expand(@%)
    let v1 = v:version[0]
    let v2 = v:version[2]
    " search in the help docs with ag-silver-search and fzf and open file
    execute "normal! :Ag /usr/share/vim/vim".v1.v2."/doc/\<cr>"
    " if we opened a help doc
    if orig_file != expand(@%)
        set nomodifiable
        " for some reason not all the tags work unless I open the real help
        " so get whichever help was found and opened through Ag
        let help_doc=expand("%:t")
        " open and close that help doc - now the tags will work
        execute "normal! :tab :help " help_doc "\<cr>:q\<cr>"
    endif
endfunction

" get some help
command! H :call Help_Ag()
```